If a series of holomorphic functions converges absolutely uniformly on a disk then the series of derivatives converges absolutely uniformly
Let $f_{i}$ be a collection of homolomorphic functions on a disk $\Delta$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |f_{i}(z)|$ converges uniformly on $\Delta$. Prove that $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}|f'(z)|$ converges uniformly on $\Delta$.
I figured out that the series $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}f'(z)$ (without the bars) converges uniformly to the derivative of $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} f_{i}(z)$ using that absolutely uniformly convergent sequence implies uniform convergence and Weierstrass theorem in Ahlfors' Complex Analysis book.
I tried to use Cauchy uniform convergence criterion on $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}|f'(z)|$, without success. I also tried differentiating the real-valued functions $|f_i(z)|$, but that doesn't appear to lead to $|f'_i(z)|$.
Thanks in advance!

Consider $f_n(z) = \frac{1}{n^2}\sqrt{1+z}$ on the unit disk $\Bbb D$. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(z)$ is uniformly convergent (to $\frac{\pi^2}{6}\sqrt{1+z}$), but all $f_n'$ are unbounded on $\Bbb D$, so $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}|f_n'(z)|$ can not be uniformly convergent.

Things are different if you work with “locally uniform convergence,” i.e. uniform convergence on all compact subsets.

Right! A counter-example. Why does the fact that the $f'_n$ are unbounded prevent the series from converging uniformly? The statement holds if we ask locally uniform convergence?
